# search by both sender name and address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Our Jenkins server sends notification e-mails that contain the header

```
From: Jenkins <nobody@nowhere>
```

How do I search for mails that exactly match this header?

Searching for `FROM: "jenkins"` or for `FROM: "nobody@nowhere"` returns results. However neither of the following work:

- `FROM: "jenkins" AND FROM: "nobody@nowhere"`
- `FROM: "jenkins <nobody@nowhere>"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Folders for arbitrary email headers in Outlook](http://superuser.com/questions/678617/search-folders-for-arbitrary-email-headers-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

- Open the e-mail you want to search on
- In Outlook 2013, go to File > Properties
- Under Internet Headers, copy the exact line for From
- Use this to search for your e-mail e.g. `"From: Jenkins <nobody@nowhere>"`

Comment: That is exactly where I got the header from that I pasted in my question. Looking at my question I see I had a case mismatch but fixing that, i.e. changing my query to `From: "Jenkins <nobody.nowhere>"` did not change anything. You have the entire thing in quotes, `"From: Jenkins <nobody@nowhere>"` returns results from mails where the body contains that string, e.g. replied to mails from Jenkins.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, best I can offer is work around and not answer. Apparently, someone else on SU had the same problem and they used Rules Wizard to categorize that e-mail. Then you search on that Category. http://superuser.com/questions/678617/search-folders-for-arbitrary-email-headers-in-outlook You can apply actions based on message headers in rules wizard, but the Outlook search itself doesn't allow you to search that way.